# SharePoint Custom form using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, list-form

I have a requirement to create a form in a SharePoint List in which there will be 10 columns like col1,col2....col10.

On submitting col1 to col5 an approval workflow should trigger and once request is approved, another team will fill mandetory columns col6 to col8 and after their submission one more email should trigger and last team will fill col9 and col10. All these columns are mandetory. Please suggest what should be the approach to implement this. Is it possible in one list only or separate lists are required?

Answer (score 2):

As SharePoint does not have have column level permission settings. If you put everything in the same list, you will have no way to avoid mistakes like fields modified by another team. Any user who has permission to edit the form, will be able to change the value in all 10 columns. It may be better to put them on separate lists.

Here is an option, List A holding 5 columns, List B col 6-8 and List C for Col 9 to 10. List D to hold all columns.

Once a new form is submitted to List A, trigger an approval workflow. And when the status changes to be approved, trigger another workflow to send an email for the next team for filling their separate form, and create a new item in List D, update first 5 column values. And do the same process for the next list, when a form is submitted and approved, update the corresponding item in List D and notify the next team to fill in required fields.